# Invariant Violation: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

This is my first project in React Native with Redux, I have a component(MyApp) which i am importing in index.js. but it is giving above error.

index.js -

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import MyApp from './component/MyApp';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import  rootReducer from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
const App = () => {
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MyApp/>
    </Provider>
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('learningRedux', () => App);
```

MyApp.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Text, View, TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPeopleFromAPI } from '../actions/index';

export class MyApp extends Component {

    render() {
        const { people, isFetching } = props.people
        return (
            <View style={{
                margin: 100,
                paddingLeft: 20,
                paddingRight: 20
            }}
            >
                <Text style={{
                    fontSize: 30,
                    textAlign: 'center'
                }}> Redux App </Text>

                <TouchableHighlight style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'blue',
                    height: 60,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center'
                }}
                    onPress={() => {
                        props.getPeople
                    }}>
                    <Text style={{
                        color: 'white'
                    }}> Fetch Data </Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                {
                    isFetching && <Text> Loading... </Text>
                }
                {
                    people.length ? (
                        people.map((person, index) => {
                            return (
                                <View key={index}>
                                    <Text> Name : {person.name} </Text>
                                    <Text> Birth Year : {person.birth_year} </Text>
                                </View>
                            )
                        }
                        )
                    ) : null
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}

mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        people: state.peopleReducer
    }
}

mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getPeople: () => dispatch(fetchPeopleFromAPI())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyApp)
```

I tried another method by creating a const MyApp instead of class and used arrow function by passing props as an argument and then only used return(not render) but it is still not working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
const App = () => {
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MyApp/>
    </Provider>
}
```

Arrow function above return `null`. If you're using curly brackets, you should add `return` keyword. Try add a `return` keyword first.

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
             <MyApp/>
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

Compare this code below.

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
const anotherAdd = (a, b) => { return a + b; };
```

That code equal. The difference is that the first one doesn't need `return` keyword since it is not using curly brackets.